# How can I simplify the For loop(c++)?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, for-loop, caesar-cipher

I found a code on the internet to encrypt user input with Caesar encryption. But in the code the loop head bother me, because we didn't have things like "message[i]" or "\0" in class. Is it possible to write this in a different way? But we had not used arrays as far as in this loop header. This is not homework or anything like that. I'm practicing for my computer science test next week and there will probably be something similar. The loop header always looked like this for example for(i = 0; i < 4; i++). How can I write this code without arrays?

How can I write the loop differently? Or do I have to change other code parts?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char message[100], ch;
    int i, key;
    cout << "Enter a message to encrypt: ";
    cin.getline(message, 100);
    cout << "Enter key: ";
    cin >> key;
    for (i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {                    //<-
        ch = message[i]; //<-
        if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
        {
            ch = ch + key;
            if (ch > 'z')
            {
                ch = ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
            }
            message[i] = ch; //<-
        }
        else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
        {
            ch = ch + key;
            if (ch > 'Z')
            {
                ch = ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
            }
            message[i] = ch; //<-
        }
    }
    cout << "Encrypted message: " << message;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"because we didn't have things like "message[i]" or "\0" in class ..."_ So you want to ask what these mean? It can be simplified using a `std::string` for the `message` variable a bit like this: `for(i = 0; i < message.length(); ++i)`

Comment: "The loop header always looked like this for example for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)" That's not a requirement. C++ allows basically anything in each part of `for`, including nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately, "I'm practicing for my computer science test next week" means we have to know the syllabus, or at least whether you will be penalised for using language features (or parts of the standard library) that haven't come up in class

Comment: Aside: where you got this from is is writing *bad* C++. Defining the locals at the top of a function has *never* been required in C++, and is a major source of bugs. `using namespace std;` is also a source of bugs, as there are thousands of *common* names used in `std`

Comment: @Caleth We are only allowed to use things that we have done in class otherwise we don't get any results.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ
 Thank you but now i got the error message error: request for member ‘length’ in ‘message’, which is of non-class type ‘char [100]’

Comment: @SorryGuys read my comment thoroughly again. You'll need to make `message` being a variable of type `std::string` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a for loop closer to what you are used to, we need to know how many letters were input. The smallest change that does that is to use `strlen` to count them.

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(message); ++i)
```

However it's better to use `std::string` to hold text, because that knows it's size.

```
int main()
{
    std::string message;
    int key;
    std::cout << "Enter a message to encrypt: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, message);
    std::cout << "Enter key: ";
    std::cin >> key;
    for (i = 0; i < message.size(); ++i)
    {
        char ch = message[i];
        if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
        {
            ch = ch + key;
            if (ch > 'z')
            {
                ch = ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
            }
            message[i] = ch; //<-
        }
        else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
        {
            ch = ch + key;
            if (ch > 'Z')
            {
                ch = ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
            }
            message[i] = ch; //<-
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Encrypted message: " << message;
    return 0;
}
```

And even better than that, you can loop over the `char`s in a string directly

```
int main()
{
    std::string message;
    int key;
    std::cout << "Enter a message to encrypt: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, message);
    std::cout << "Enter key: ";
    std::cin >> key;
    for (char & ch : message) // <- N.b. char &, we are modifying the `char` objects owned by message
    {
        if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
        {
            ch = ch + key;
            if (ch > 'z')
            {
                ch = ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
            }
        }
        else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
        {
            ch = ch + key;
            if (ch > 'Z')
            {
                ch = ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Encrypted message: " << message;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but it's a bit complicated for me unfortunately.  Is it possible to write for (char & ch : message) differently? We didn't have something like this in class yet, unfortunately.

Comment: @SorryGuys no, just use whichever of these you have covered in class. `for ( : )` is a separate kind of loop to `for ( ; ; )`, it just uses the same keyword (like `while() {}` and `do {} while()` both use the keyword `while`)

Comment: Thank you. Is this a for each loop? How do I write this in a normal for loop? Sorry.

Comment: @SorryGuys C++ calls it ranged-for, but yes, it loops over each element of a sequence. It is defined [as if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Explanation) it were a block of statements containing an ordinary `for( ; ; )` loop, but you shouldn't write like that yourself.

Comment: one last question please. How can I rewrite the char ch = message[i] in your first solution? I want to have a variable output (string).

Answer (score 0):

Look at this snippet. Sorry if I have made a mistake with syntax, but this is enough to give you a general idea.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
  
using namespace std;
  
int main() {
    char message[100];
    int key;
    
    cout << "Enter a message to encrypt: ";
    cin.getline(message, 100);
    
    cout << "Enter key: ";
    cin >> key;

    encrypt(message, key);

    cout << "Encrypted message: " << message;
    
    return 0;
}

void encrypt(char& message, const int key) {
    for (char& ch : message) {
        if (islower (ch))
            ch = encrypt (ch + key, 'a', 'z');
        else if (isupper (message[i]))
            ch = encrypt (ch + key, 'A', 'Z');
    }   
}

char encrypt(const char ch, const char lo, const char hi) {
    return ch % hi ? lo + (chi % hi) : ch;  
}
```

Comment: The `if (ch > 'z')` test is after adding `key`, it does matter.

Comment: @Caleth I have updated my answer. You're right. I have missed this point.